# Как получить данные в Activity из EditText в RecyclerView

Tags: java, android

В общем, у меня есть `RecyclerView`, он отображает `CardView` по заданному макету. В макете `CardView` у меня есть `EditText`. Пользователь может что-то туда вписать.
Под `RecyclerView` у меня есть кнопка, при нажатии этой кнопки вызывается метод из активности и в этом методе мне нужно получить данные из `EditText` каждого `CardView`.

Как это реализовать?

PS: Не выкладываю пример кода, потому что по-моему все четко изложил. Дайте мне идею, я дальше подхвачу.

Answer (score 3):

1. В адаптере заведите `public List<String> editTextsTexts = new ArrayList<>();` (или массив, если число ячеек списка статично)
2. В onBindViewHolder методе адаптера повесьте `TextWatcher` методом `onTextChangeListener` на ваш `EditText`
3. В `afterTextChange` TextWatcher-а из п.2 обновляйте/назначайте значение соответствующему элементу списка из п.1 так: `editTextsTexts.add(position, editable);`
4. Теперь у вас есть список, хранящий текст всех ваших `EditText` и доступный из адаптера.
5. Получить его можно в активити так: `((ADAPTER_CLASS_NAME) recuclerView.getAdapter()).editTextsTexts;`